# How to assign a quosure to another object?

Tags: r, rlang, quosure

I want to change the name of some argument.

Following [the guidelines](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lifecycle/vignettes/lifecycle.html#deprecating-arguments), I should use `lifecycle::deprecate_warn` and then attribute the old name to the new name.

However, in my function, the argument is normally used with quosures, so the attribution fails with an error:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lifecycle)
library(rlang)
my_fun = function(df, cols, .vars = deprecated()){
  if (quo_is_missing(enquo(cols)) && !quo_is_missing(enquo(.vars))) {
    deprecate_warn("0.1.6", "my_fun(.vars=)", "my_fun(cols=)")
    cols <- .vars #error is thrown here
  }
  select(df, {{cols}})
}

my_fun(iris, cols=Sepal.Length) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length
#> 1          5.1
#> 2          4.9
#> 3          4.7
#> 4          4.6
#> 5          5.0
#> 6          5.4
my_fun(iris, .vars=Sepal.Length) %>% head()
#> Warning: The `.vars` argument of `my_fun()` is deprecated as of <NA> 0.1.6.
#> Please use the `cols` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
#> Error in my_fun(iris, .vars = Sepal.Length): objet 'Sepal.Length' introuvable
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I blindly tried various things with `enquo` and others but nothing worked.

How can I attribute the old name to the new name?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `{{` is shorthand for `!!enquo()`. Since you want to quote either `cols` or `.vars`, depending on which one is missing, I suggest doing `!!` and `enquo()` separately:

```
my_fun = function(df, cols, .vars = deprecated()){
  if (quo_is_missing(enquo(cols)) && !quo_is_missing(enquo(.vars))) {
    deprecate_warn("0.1.6", "my_fun(.vars=)", "my_fun(cols=)")
    cols <- enquo(.vars)    # Quote .vars, if cols is missing
  }
  else cols <- enquo(cols)  # Quote cols, if cols is not missing

  select(df, !!cols)        # Unquote with !!, instead of {{, which is !!enquo()
}

my_fun(iris, cols=Sepal.Length) %>% head()    # Works
my_fun(iris, .vars=Sepal.Length) %>% head()   # Also works
```

If you absolutely must use `{{`, the only way to modify the expression that gets captured is to change how the function is called. This can be done with a little bit of recursion (i.e., having `my_fun` call itself):

```
my_fun = function(df, cols, .vars = deprecated()){
  if (quo_is_missing(enquo(cols)) && !quo_is_missing(enquo(.vars))) {
    deprecate_warn("0.1.6", "my_fun(.vars=)", "my_fun(cols=)")
    return( my_fun(df, {{.vars}}) )   # .vars will be captured as cols
  }

  select(df, {{cols}})
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a solution that I have considered. Unfortunately, I'm not really using `dplyr::select()` but an internal function that expects a quosure. It would need some meaningful refactoring to change the internal function as well, so I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Sorry, it came out wrong, I meant that my internal function expects a name, not a quosure. Just like `dplyr::select`.

Comment: Sorry, the last line must really be `select(df, {{cols}})` so that it mimics how my function works. Your answer is very good, but it would require a bit too much refactoring. If there is no other solution I will accept it though.

Comment: Unfortunately, `{{` is too restrictive for what you are trying to do. It captures the expression supplied to `cols` and immediately uses it. Since there is no gap between the two actions, there is no place where you can modify the expression. The only way to change what gets captured by `{{` would be to modify how `my_fun` is called, possibly with the help of a wrapper.

Comment: Of course, such a wrapper could be the function itself ;) Please see my edit.